# How to plot days data on top of month data in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, bar-chart, histogram

I have date data in R that lists specific dates across 11 months, that looks something like this (except I have many more data points):

```
Intake.Date = c("2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26",
"2023-01-26", "2023-01-26","2023-02-02", "2023-01-31", "2023-02-07", "2023-01-31",
"2023-02-16", "2023-02-18", "2023-02-18","2023-03-02", "2023-03-02", "2023-03-02",
"2023-03-06", "2023-03-06", "2023-03-06", "2023-03-08")
```

I would like to layer 2 graphs: A bar graph showing the count for each month in the data, and on top of that showing the count for each day. I started off with this:

```
ggplot()+
geom_histogram(data = AFOBC_Pathology_Data, mapping = aes(Intake.Date), bins = 11)+
geom_bar(data = AFOBC_Pathology_Data, mapping = aes(Intake.Date), fill = 'cyan')
```

Which produces the following graph:
[image]

And this is close to what I want, but I know the bins (grey bars) aren't correct, because I know I don't have the same number of dates in each month. However, if I try to map the the days and months on the same graph like this:

```
ggplot()+
geom_bar(data = AFOBC_Pathology_Data, mapping = aes(format(Intake.Date,'%b')), fill = 'grey')+
geom_bar(data = AFOBC_Pathology_Data, mapping = aes(Intake.Date), fill = 'cyan'),
```

I get the following error:

> Error in `mapped_discrete()`: ! Can't convert `x`  to .
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your second approach is, that in the first `geom_bar` you map a character string aka the month abbreviation aka a discrete variable on `x`, whereas in the second it is still a date.

If you want to have bars showing the counts for the month while also displaying the days I would suggest to compute the counts manually outside of `ggplot()` and use a `geom_rect`, e.g. something like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(lubridate)

AFOBC_Pathology_Data_binned <- AFOBC_Pathology_Data |> 
  mutate(
    month = format(Intake.Date, "%b")
  ) |> 
  summarise(
    start = floor_date(min(Intake.Date), "month"), 
    end = ceiling_date(max(Intake.Date), "month"),
    count = n(),
    .by = "month"
  )


ggplot(AFOBC_Pathology_Data) +
  geom_rect(
    data = AFOBC_Pathology_Data_binned,
    aes(
      xmin = start, xmax = end,
      ymin = 0, ymax = count
    ),
    fill = "grey"
  ) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(Intake.Date),
    fill = "cyan"
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
AFOBC_Pathology_Data <- data.frame(
  Intake.Date = c(
    "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26",
    "2023-01-26", "2023-01-26", "2023-02-02", "2023-01-31", "2023-02-07", "2023-01-31",
    "2023-02-16", "2023-02-18", "2023-02-18", "2023-03-02", "2023-03-02", "2023-03-02",
    "2023-03-06", "2023-03-06", "2023-03-06", "2023-03-08"
  )
)
AFOBC_Pathology_Data$Intake.Date <- as.Date(AFOBC_Pathology_Data$Intake.Date)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was hoping there was a more elegant way to manage it, but robust beats out elegant every time